# IBM、Qiskitに関して

Tags: python, quantum-computing

下記のサイトを参考にIBMQiskitのチュートリアルを動かしています。
ソース自体は何も変更していません。
https://github.com/qulacs/quantum-native-dojo/blob/933f701ecf07ee2d3360be2af70fe7a7c46926c1/notebooks/3.2_Qiskit_IBMQ.ipynb

Google colabで実行しているのですが、実行後に下記の部分でエラーが出ます。

**ソースコード**

```
#least busyだったbackendを選ぶ
backend_sim = backend_lb

#量子回路qcを指定したバックエンド(backend_sim)で4096回実行する。
result = execute(qc, backend_sim, shots=4096).result()
```

**エラーメッセージ**

```
TranspilerError: 'Number of qubits (2) in circuit0 is greater than maximum (1) in the coupling_map'
```

このエラーの解決方法が分かりません、教えていただけないでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

こちらで試してみると、同じエラーが発生します。その際の `backend_lb` は `ibmq_armonk` になります。

```
>>> backend_lb = least_busy(provider.backends(simulator=False, operational=True))
>>> backend_lb
<IBMQBackend('ibmq_armonk') from IBMQ(hub='ibm-q', group='open', project='main')>
```

`ibmq_armonk` の qubit数 は `1` なので、量子ゲートの `coupling map` は以下の様になっています。

```
>>> backend_lb.configuration().n_qubits
1
>>> list(map(lambda x: x.coupling_map, backend_lb.configuration().gates))
[[[0]], [[0]], [[0]], [[0]]]
```

これでは 2 qubit数の計算をすることはできません。。。

> TranspilerError: 'Number of qubits (2) in circuit0 is greater than maximum (1) in the coupling_map'

したがって、qubit数が `2` 以上のバックエンドを選ぶ必要があります。

```
>>> list(map(lambda b: print('{:>20}: {:>2}'
.format(b.name(), b.configuration().n_qubits)), provider.backends()))
 ibmq_qasm_simulator: 32
              ibmqx2:  5
   ibmq_16_melbourne: 14
           ibmq_vigo:  5
        ibmq_ourense:  5
         ibmq_london:  5
     ibmq_burlington:  5
          ibmq_essex:  5
         ibmq_armonk:  1
```

`ibmq_qasm_simulator` と `ibmq_armonk` 以外であれば問題ないかと思います。

Comment: 上記の内容で解決できました。大変参考になりました。